# is this language context free?

Tags: computer-science, formal-systems

I need an NPDA for the following language if it is context-free, and if it isn't I need a proof using the pumping lemma that it is not a CFL:

$$L_1=\{w_1w_2 \in \{a,b\}^* : |w_1| = |w_2|,w_1\neq w_2\}$$

Comment: when w1w2ϵ{a,b}*

Comment: Do you have any guesses? Is it context-free or not?

Comment: i think its not contextfree but i know some similar languages like w1cw2 are contextfree.

Comment: It is always helpful, to readers, to provide some context or motivation when asking a question.  Providing enough background also helps the asker - namely it helps avoid the question "Isn't this homework?"

Comment: Voting to close as the answer is in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$ S \to aSa | bSb | aXb | bXa $$
$$ X \to aXa | bXb | aXb | bXa | \epsilon $$

Comment: $S \rightarrow bXa \rightarrow baXba \rightarrow baba$

Comment: Of course, Raphael.  And you can apply the pumping lemma to the complement, so the language is not context free.

Comment: CFL is not closed against complement.